# Mask Alternative chars in a String using Regex in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I need a regex pattern, which can mask alternative 2 chars in a string in java.. But the input string we cannot predict. For Example

```
String pattern = "abcdefgh";
OutPut: "ab\*\*ef\*\*"
```

So the expression should be common one. Not specific for the above string

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pattern = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    System.out.println(pattern.replaceAll("(\\w{2})(\\w{2})", "$1**"));
}
```

O/P :

```
ab**ef**ij**mn**
```

`replaceAll("(\\w{2})(\\w{2})", "$1**"))` ==> Replaces 2 groups 2 chars each with "2 chars,**".

Note that if you have odd chars, the last char will not be masked. This should fix it == > `System.out.println(pattern.replaceAll("(\\w{2})(\\w{2})", "$1**").replaceAll("(\\w{2})\\w$", "$1*"));`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but one thing i found that, if am giving odd number of chars, like String ex ="1234567"; then out will be 12**567 Can you modify this to 12**56*

Comment: @Jam - Note that using `Pattern` and `Matcher` here would be a better solution :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me :)